# Things to know about a motor when setting up a circuit?

Tags: voltage, batteries

I'm trying to build an electric bike. However, when looking at motors online, they often have statistics, such as [this.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/36-48V-Electric-Bicycle-E-Bike-26-Front-Rear-Wheel-Conversion-Kit-Cycling-Motor/322247604604?epid=1080434799&hash=item4b0774397c:m:mJN-WoBojMA9MrSPby1OlOw)

```
Specifications:
* Wheel Size: 26"      * Spokes: Steel, 12G×2.6mm
* Max load capacity: 150kg (36V500WR、36V500WF) 
* Max load capacity: 200kg (48V1000WR、48V1000WF、48V1000WRC) 
* Max load capacity: 250kg (48V1500WR) 
* Tire: Nylon              
* Motor: Brushless Gearless       
* Rim: Alloy double wall

Model     Wheel     Power        Max speed   Torque
36V500WR    Rear    500W / 36V      22 mph      35 N.M
36V500WF    Front
48V1000WR   Rear    1000W / 48V     28 mph      45 N.M
48V1000WF   Front
48V1000WRC  Rear    1000W / 48V     28 mph      45 N.M
48V1500WR   Rear    1500W / 48V     34 mph      48 N.M
```

I know some basic electrical engineering terms, but I'm confused on what I should be looking for in this instance.
I want to balance efficiency with speed, and am also wondering in advance what batteries/factors I should be looking out for.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Chris has edited your question to include the specifications which you should have done so we don't have to follow a link to figure out what you're talking about. (The edit should be approved shortly.) Please edit your question to ask for clarification on one or two specific points.

Comment: *balance efficiency with speed* – there is nothing to *balance* here. The lowest speed is most efficient because the power needed to cope with the wind squares with speed. The power needed to run against a slope is linear to speed.

Comment: You only need to use grade XII physics to perform energy , power and inertia to convert mass, torque and acceleration and related to battery current limit, VAh , ESR voltage drop, heat rise, runtime, while V/RPM is constant for no load and ideal match load is 84%Voc for maximum power transfer on peak to RMS voltages using Univ level Electrical equations. It’s just a clever use of Ohm’s Law.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably not find enough information to do any kind of engineering analysis to select an electric bicycle conversion kit.

Strictly speaking efficiency for a vehicle is mechanical power output divided by electrical power input. Input power is equal to output power plus losses. Losses include electrical losses in the controller and motor and mechanical losses in the motor and drive components. Purchasing the most efficient battery, motor, controller and bicycle parts will mean less of the energy stored in the battery is lost and more is used to move the bicycle and rider.

The mechanical power is used to move the bicycle and rider. On a level surface, all of the power is used to overcome the rolling friction of the tires and the aerodynamic drag acting on the rider and bicycle. Aerodynamic drag power is approximately proportional to speed cubed. Higher speed means greatly increased drag and more energy used for a given distance. When climbing a hill, energy is used to raise the total mass to a higher elevation, but some of that energy can be later recovered by coasting down hill.

Answer (score 0):

> - Wheel Size: 26"      * Spokes: Steel, 12G×2.6mm

That bit should be clear. 1" = 25.4 mm.

> - Max load capacity: 150kg (36V500WR、36V500WF)

The various models give you the rated maximum load (kg), the motor voltage (V), the motor power (W) and rear (R) or front (F) wheel versions.

> - Motor: Brushless Gearless

All of the e-bikes are using brushless motors. They have no wearing brushes but require a special controller to run them.

- Rim: Alloy double wall

The wheel, battery and controller are heavy. The wheels need to be rated for this.

```
Model     Wheel     Power        Max speed   Torque
36V500WR    Rear    500W / 36V      22 mph      35 N.M
```

Most of these motors have a freewheel mechanism similar to your rear chain sprocket. If you exceed the rated speed the motor won't be able to keep up with the wheel and will freewheel. You will be providing all the power by your legs.

The torque should be specified in Nm (newton-metres) - small 'm'.

You'll need to use the correct voltage battery pack. Battery duration will be given by

$$ T = \frac {Wh}{W_{avg}} $$ where *T* is time, *Wh* is the watt-hour rating of the battery pack and *W<sub>avg</sub>* is the average power you use on a run.

My Kalkhoff Agattu has a 250 W motor mounted below the pedals and drives the chain and regular back wheel. As a result I was able to reduce the size of the rear cog wheel to gain some extra speed. I reckon that in normal riding on my flat route that the motor is giving 150 W and I'm putting in another 150 W or so to maintain 30 kph sitting in an upright position.

500 W is a lot of power and I would be cautious about installing it in a bike that had not been specifically designed to take the stresses involved.

You will also need a matching motor controller rated for the voltage and power of your battery and motor. A throttle and charger are also required. Try and keep the centre of gravity as low as you can.

---

From the comments:

> So the 1000 W just has more room of how fast it can go, at cost of battery charge, but both going at the same speed (power), they'll deplete at the same rate?

You will see from the specifications that the 1000 W wheel does not have a maximum speed of twice that of the 500 W wheel. This means that they have changed the internal gearing between the motor and the hub. Some of the extra power will go into increased speed. The big difference will be hill-climbing speed. The smaller motor has less power and so even at full voltage will not run at maximum speed on a climb.

Comment: What exactly does the motor power (W) mean? What's the difference between the 500W version and the 1000W version?

Comment: The W in the part number is the motor power rating in watts and 'W' is the shorthand symbol for watts. From this you can work out the maximum current and range for a given battery. The 1000 W version is twice as powerful as the 500 W version but when on max power will deplete the battery at twice the rate.

Comment: So the 1000W just has more room of how fast it can go, at cost of battery charge, but both going at the same speed(power), they'll deplete at the same rate?

Comment: See the update.